# How to select row which have sub rows?

Tags: r

These days I am working with R and I use to use **h02** data-set. This data-set can be import by

```
library(fpp)
data <- h02
data
```

When I ran above the code I got this output.

```
           Jan       Feb       Mar       Apr       May       Jun       Jul       Aug       Sep       Oct       Nov       Dec
1991                                                             0.4297950 0.4009060 0.4321590 0.4925430 0.5023690 0.6026520
1992 0.6601190 0.3362200 0.3513480 0.3798080 0.3618010 0.4105340 0.4833887 0.4754634 0.5347610 0.5686061 0.5952233 0.7712578
1993 0.7515028 0.3875543 0.4272832 0.4138902 0.4288588 0.4701264 0.5092097 0.5584430 0.6015141 0.6329471 0.6996054 0.9630805
1994 0.8193253 0.4376698 0.5061213 0.4704912 0.5106963 0.5405138 0.5581189 0.6728521 0.6858974 0.6896920 0.7413036 0.8133076
1995 0.8031126 0.4752582 0.5525723 0.5271078 0.5612498 0.5889776 0.6231336 0.7408372 0.7253718 0.8158030 0.8140095 0.9266531
1996 0.9372759 0.5287616 0.5593399 0.5778717 0.6149274 0.5941888 0.7077584 0.7195020 0.7443237 0.8048551 0.7885423 0.9710894
```

That was the sample of full data-set. My problem is when I tried to view first row of the data-set I used this command

`head(data, 1)`

That should be output first row of the data-set but I have got this output

```
          Jul
1991 0.429795
```

**But my expected output is**

```
           Jan       Feb       Mar       Apr       May       Jun       Jul       Aug       Sep       Oct       Nov       Dec
1991                                                             0.4297950 0.4009060 0.4321590 0.4925430 0.5023690 0.6026520
```

When I check columns, This data-set have no columns and have only rows. each year row has sub month rows. How can I select year row with all month rows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because `data` isn't a datafame, it's a time-series object.  You can check this

```
str(data)
Time-Series [1:204] from 1992 to 2008: 0.43 0.401 0.432 0.493 0.502 ...
```

First convert `data` to a dataframe, then your `head` command will work as you expect.

```
Month <-  factor(cycle(data), levels = 1:12, labels = month.abb)
df <- tapply(data, list(year = floor(time(data)), month = Month), c)
head(df, 1)

      month
year   Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun      Jul      Aug      Sep      Oct      Nov      Dec
  1991  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA 0.429795 0.400906 0.432159 0.492543 0.502369 0.602652
```

Answer (score 1):

I have found the another solution for this. It is `window()` keyword and you have to give the start year, month and end year, month to get specific row.

```
window(data, start=c(1991,1), end=c(1991,12))
```

**Output -:**

```
          Jul      Aug      Sep      Oct      Nov      Dec
1991 0.429795 0.400906 0.432159 0.492543 0.502369 0.602652
```

From Jan to Jun time series have 0 values there for those months not counted.